# numexpr, check for the presence of VML

Tags: python, numexpr

There are many different [Python distributions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDistributions) that allow for the installation of complementary modules, sometimes using different tools so that, when one installs a new package, it's not always immediately apparent how the package was built.

A specific question that I'd like to ask in this respect is, was my `numexpr` module built against the [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) libraries and, more specifically, the Vector Mathematical Functions code ([VML](https://software.intel.com/en.../mkl-developer-reference-c-vector-mathematical-functions)).

Is it possible to check, using Python, if the `numexpr` module installed by my distribution supports VML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numexpr as ne
ne.use_vml
```

Comment: import numexpr as ne;ne.use_vml